# How can I deploy a laravel application to a server

Tags: server, laravel-8

I currently have developed a Laravel application on my localhost. We have a server in the office which is only accessible to Office computers. I want to deploy my Laravel application to that server so they can access it. what steps should I take after developing the application to make it live on server. A detailed guide will be highly appreciated as I have no experience working with the servers.

Answer (score 1):

I found this time ago, and help me a lot to setup a server and introduce me to server stuff, the CI/DI process, the repo pipelines, etc. Enjoy it!

https://lorisleiva.com/deploy-your-laravel-app-from-scratch